# IIS7 - 401 Unauthorized error while reading external xml file from a swf (flash)

Tags: xml, iis-7, flash, http-status-code-401, unauthorized

I am getting a 401 unauthorized error when I try to read an XML file from a flash SWF file in IIS7. The file is located right next to the SWF file in the file system.

When I browse to the XML file through the browser, I get the following:

> HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized You do
>   not have permission to view this
>   directory or page because of the
>   access control list (ACL)
>   configuration or encryption settings
>   for this resource on the Web server.

I have given IIS_IUSRS full permission to that folder but still getting the same error. Is this something IIS7 specific?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue, for some reason the xml file in question had "encrypt contents to secure data" enabled. Once I disabled the option, it started working fine.

To disable "encrypt contents to secure data", right click the file -> under general/attributes, click "advanced" -> under "compress or encrypt attributes", deselect the option if it is already selected.

Hopefully somebody will find this helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Can you check that IIS_IUSRS really has access to the XML file (not just the folder that the file is in)?

Comment: Yeah it does. I figured out the issue, see below.